# Why asm in jersey-bundle 1.17.1 is scope provided?

Tags: java, maven, jersey, java-bytecode-asm

I'm using the jersey-bundle dependency (v1.17.1) and get a `ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor`.

This happens because asm's depepndency in jersey-bundle is defined as provided, thus not retrieving the asm jar when packaging my app.

Why is asm defined as provided in the [jersey-bundle pom](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.17.1)?

```
<dependency>
<groupId>asm</groupId>
<artifactId>asm</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of this bundle says :

> A bundle containing code of all jar-based modules that provide JAX-RS
>   and Jersey-related features. Such a bundle is *only intended* for
>   developers that do not use Maven's dependency system. The bundle does
>   not include code for contributes, tests and samples.

In others words : it's buggy as a maven dependencies ;-)

There is an issue about it - [JERSEY-599](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-599) (closed - but not really solved).